# How to get the start date of the week by week number of year in Hive? First day of week should be Monday

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a week number of year in ISO format and I want to get start date of this week in Hive. First date of week is Monday.
Example: year 2020 week 50 - start date should be 2020-12-07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, where `year` and `week` are the corresponding column names of your table.

```
select date(
    from_unixtime(
        unix_timestamp(concat(year,'-',week,'-','1'), 'yyyy-w-u')
    )
) from <your_table_name>;
```